# preg_match_all() html tags

Tags: php, regex

Using preg_match_all(), I want to match something like:

`...randomtext...>MATCH1</a>" (MATCH2)"...randomtext...` EDIT: to clarify, this is exactly the string I'm trying to extract data from, including the brackets, quotes, angle-brackets etc.

Here's what I've tried: `preg_match_all("/^>(.+?)</a>\" \((.+?)\)\"$/", $htmlfile, $matches);`

It should extract `MATCH1` as `$matches[1][0]` and `MATCH2` as `$matches[2][0]`

Any idea why it isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: so to be clear, you're trying to match all text within the first tag as well as after a `" ` after the first tag?  Can you elaborate on the pattern you're trying to match?

Comment: ^ is beginning of line. Is it what you want? Personally I find your example is too unclear. And btw, you need to escape more characters. http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question - I'm trying to extract MATCH1 and MATCH2 from the specified string: `>MATCH1</a>" (MATCH2)"` it could have anything on either side of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't escape your end tag `</a>`

This should work:

```
preg_match_all("/>(.+?)<\/a>\" \((.*?)\)/", $htmlfile, $matches);
```

See [Codepad example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pzqAEB).

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `/` in your pattern, and you **don't** want your pattern anchored to `^` and `$`

So probably this will work: `preg_match_all("/>(.+?)<\/a>\" \((.+?)\)\"/", $htmlfile, $matches);`

Comment: Thanks smathy! I really appreciate it!